# F# syntax to change a record with a function then update the new record

Tags: f#

I'm learning F# (slowly).

How do I fix this?

Explanation: "reset m" initializes the model record and returns a new model record. "update msg m" returns a new model record.

What I am trying to do here with SelectMsg  is *first update/reset* the "model" m, *then* set the property, SelectedOutterRow, of the *new model* (produced by reset).

This Fails:

```
let update msg m =
      match msg with
      | SelectMsg rId -> 
            reset m |> { m with SelectedOutterRow = rId }
```

This succeeds, except the original **non-reset** model is returned

```
let update msg m =
      match msg with
      | SelectMsg rId -> 
            reset m |> ignore
           { m with SelectedOutterRow = rId }
```

where

```
type Model =
      { OutterRows: OutterRow.Model list
        SelectedOutterRow: Guid option }

let reset m = 
      let rows = 
        m.OutterRows
        |> List.map (fun r -> OutterRow.reset r)
      { m with OutterRows = rows; SelectedOutterRow = None }
```

So, in short, how do I write the lambda to first reset the model, update the model, and lastly return the new model?

Thank you for any help.

TIA

Comment: `{ reset m with SelectedOutterRow = rId }` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer to have the "steps" in front of you, you could give the reset record a name so that you can then refer to it. The way to give things names in F# is the `let` keyword:

```
| SelectMsg rId ->
    let r = reset m
    { r with SelectedOutterRow = rId }
```

Or you could skip the name and do it all in one expression:

```
| SelectMsg rId ->
    { reset m with SelectedOutterRow = rId }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code in the question does not work, is that `reset m` does not change `m`. Instead it returns a new record.

Writing `{ reset m with SelectedOutterRow = rId }` thus takes `m`, passes it to the `reset` function, which returns a new record. The `with` statement takes this new record, and returns another new record where the `SelectedOutterRow` has been set to `rId`.

So at no point is any existing record mutated - by default F# does not allow mutation. In every case you have an expression which returns a new record.